# Distribution of the square of the euclidean norm of a gaussian vector with diagonal covariance matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared

Let $X\sim\mathcal{N}_d(0,\Sigma)$ be a $d$-dimensional gaussian vector, where $0\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ is diagonal. I'm interested on the distribution of:
$$
||X||^2
$$
I know that it follows a generalized chi-squared distribution , in general of the form $\tilde{\chi}^2(w,k,\lambda,m,s)$, where I used the notations of:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution

In my particular case I think that $w = diag(\Sigma)$ (the vector whose entries are the diagonal's entries of $\Sigma$), $k = (1,1,\dots,1)$ , $\lambda = (0,0,\dots,0)$ , $m = s = 0$.

I would like to know how to prove this fact since I'm kind of "new" about the generalized chi squared distribution. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: $X = \Sigma^{1/2}Z$ with $Z \sim N(0, I)$, so $\|X\|^2 = Z^T \Sigma Z = \sum_{j}\sigma_j^2 Z_j^2$.

Comment: Where $\sigma_j^2$ are the entries of the diagonal of $\Sigma$ and $Z_j^2\sim\chi_{(1)}^2$ are indipendent chi-squared distributed random variables. Is it correct?

Comment: Hi: Since the matrix is diagonal, one can assume that the marginals are gaussian. In the case where the matrix was not diagonal, one could not make that assumption.

Comment: @markleeds hi! Thank you, it's finally clear!

Comment: @Luca Onnis: You're welcome. I hope it helped some. I don't know of a reference or I would have provided one.

Comment: No problem, I think I understand why it's the case! I have another question somehow related to this one.. I have posted it yesterday but unfortunately I haven't received any reply. It's very interesting and I'm convinced it has already been studied but I just can not find the right reference. Could you please give a check to my last question? Thank you in advance!